# Windows ML ONNX model gives weird coordinates for boxes

Tags: c#, computer-vision, object-detection, ml.net

I used [www.customvision.ai](http://www.customvision.ai) to create a ONNX model to do some object detection on images. This included a python example on how to use it. But I want to use it in C#.
I did found some examples on how to use it in C#, but all were different.

There was an official one from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/object-detection-onnx). But this was way to complicated. First off the model output was different from mine. second,you have to make so many helper methods and not much is explained. I'm just a beginner.

I also tried the example where the [object builder (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/object-detection-model-builder) is used in visual studio. This generated a much simpler code base. But when I tried it with my images, it failed.

Then I found another [example](https://blog.hompus.nl/2020/09/25/get-all-prediction-scores-from-your-onnx-model-with-ml-net/). With this I could use the ONNX model I created in computervision.
It gave me an output, but the coordinates for the boxes are not what I expected
[image]

Do I have to use these values to calculate the effective coordinates?

The score works. There is a buoy in the image.I tried a another image without a buoy and the scores were below 10%.

I have a test project on github: https://github.com/puppetSpace/MlTest
this includes the ONNX model and an image to test with.
The goal of the object detection is to detect buoys in the  water.

**extra info of my model:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was in the documentation at the time you were working on this project, but a note was added clarifying how coordinates from a model trained using Model Builder are normalized / scaled.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/object-detection-model-builder#web-api

Here's the note:

> The bounding box coordinates are normalized for a width of 800 pixels and a height of 600 pixels. To scale the bounding box coordinates for your image in further post-processing, you need to:
>
> Multiply the top and bottom coordinates by the original image height, and multiply the left and right coordinates by the original image width.
> Divide the top and bottom coordinates by 600, and divide the left and right coordinates by 800.
>
> For example, given the original image dimensions,actualImageHeight and actualImageWidth, and a ModelOutput called prediction, the following code snippet shows how to scale the BoundingBox coordinates:
>
> ```cs
> var top = originalImageHeight * prediction.Top / 600;
> var bottom = originalImageHeight * prediction.Bottom / 600;
> var left = originalImageWidth * prediction.Left / 800;
> var right = originalImageWidth * prediction.Right / 800;
> ```
>
> An image may have more than one bounding box, so the same process needs to be applied to each of the bounding boxes in the image.

Comment: Did that. Still doesn't give me the correct coordinates

Comment: In the Model Builder Evaluate step, if you try the model with your image. Does it correctly draw bounding boxes?

Comment: When is use the quick test on customvision.ai, it shows the border around the object. [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/pot5uxd)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I thought you were using [ML.NET Model Builder](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/machinelearning-ai/ml-dotnet/model-builder) to train your model, not Cognitive Services (Custom Vision). They're different cases as you mentioned in your original post. My response refers to models trained using ML.NET Model Builder. When you say using Model Builder fails, can you clarify that a bit more? 

For consuming Custom Vision models, check out this section of the workshop which does just that for your scenario. https://mlnet-workshop.azurewebsites.net/category/ONNX

Answer (score 0):

I believe the output values are ratios of the width and height. Therefore, this actual width and height are found by (in C#):

```
var pixelLeft = leftRatio * imageWidth;
var pixelTop = topRatio * imageHeight;
var pixelRight = rightRatio * imageWidth;
var pixelBottom = bottomRatio * imageHeight;
```

If you want to overlay boxes on to images within `System.Drawing`, the parameters for [creating a rectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) are:

```
public void DrawRectangle (System.Drawing.Pen pen, int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

or

```
public void DrawRectangle (System.Drawing.Pen pen, float x, float y, float width, float height);
```

Therefore a couple of adjustments are required:

```
var x = pixelLeft;
var y = pixelTop;
var width = pixelRight - pixelLeft;
var height = pixelTop - pixelBottom;
```